# Node js - how to publish a package and let user run a single command to start the server

Tags: node.js, npm

I have made a npm package for the first time. For my daily dev, I have used `npm start` to start the server and then user can use localhost:3000 to view the pages.

When I try to publish that to end users, I can still ask people to use `npm install` > `npm start` to use the package. However, it doesn't sound decent.

How can I make people being able to use:

```
npm install myPackage
myPackage start
```

to start the server and then they can open localhost: 3000 directly?

Comment: how it will make a big difference if you change it from `npm start` to `myPackage start`. BTW the thing you are trying to do requires an executable js file which can run.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki There is no much difference. But I wish people could install it via npm install, not download a .zip file unzip it. And if I make just publish a package people still need to go to node_modules/myPackage and then type npm start.

Comment: publishing package is a great thing but you included in the question that you want  a command for your npm package so that users can directly run, my comment was in that context

Comment: @ArpitSolanki yep, actually I just want to publish a package which people can run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a global module and attach it to a bin command.

[Here's the tutorial for that by npm itself](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm).

In your package.json file, you can add this:

```
"bin": {
  "your-command": "bin/path/to/js/file.js"
}
```

and then whenever the user installs your module globally, then they can directly type in that command and the js file will execute your code.

Comment: include the solution here, not just the link. Link only answers are not accepted here

Comment: @ArpitSolanki sure buddy.

Comment: Cool please follow this in your other answers as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to create global package for your module so that it can be installed

```
npm i -g module
```

then provide some config file like gulpfile.js which will be used by your package to carry out the task to start server any other task